# I have functioning code, but I would like it to return the list object name instead of the position

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Apples = 1
Oranges = 0
Bananas = 1
Grapes = 0

list1 = [Apples, Oranges, Bananas, Grapes]
y = len(list1)

for x in range(0,y):
    if list1[x] == 1:
        print (x)
```

This code will print out the locations of the variables with values of 1: 0,2

Would like this to print out the names of the variables instead of the locations (so Apples and Bananas).

Edited code with dictionary method (printing out all fruit names though):

```
Apples = 1
Oranges = 0
Bananas = 1
Grapes = 0


FruitValues = {"Apples": Apples,"Oranges": Oranges,"Bananas": 
Bananas,"Grapes": Grapes}

myFruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Grapes"]


for x in myFruits:
    if x in FruitValues:
        print(f"{x}")
```

Here is an idea but not working:

```
Apples = 1
Oranges = 0
Bananas = 1
Grapes = 0


FruitValues = {"Apples": Apples,"Oranges": Oranges,"Bananas": 
Bananas,"Grapes": Grapes}

myFruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Grapes"]


for x, y in FruitValues.items():
    if y in FruitValues == 1:
        print(y)
```

Comment: The list object has no idea that the values used to construct it were referenced by those names. If the names are important, use a `dict` like `{'Apples': 1, 'Oranges': 0, 'Bananas': 1, 'Grapes': 0}`.

Comment: Hi Sam. It looks what you want is something like a `dicti`ionary, instead of a list. Thay way, you create name-pair values.

Comment: Variable names are *code*, not *data*.

Comment: Your list *doesn't contain variables* - it is EXACTLY the same as if you had written `[1, 0, 1, 0]`.  For the value `1`, there's no conceivable way to tell whether that value came from `Apples` or `Bananas`, it's the same object either way.

Comment: The general rule that is true across every language (except for that awful PHP language) is that whenever you think "Dynamically reference a variable" or "Variable variable names" instead think: "Dictionary". It's a good one to remember as this comes up often and can lead you down some ugly paths, like the one you are on now.

Comment: Thanks all.  Ok I will play around with dictionary and see how that works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a dictionary to assign values to elements

```
FruitValues = {
  "Apples": 1,
  "Oranges": 0,
  "Bananas": 1,
  "Grapes": 0
}
```

then you can create a list of fruits

```
myFruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Grapes"]
```

the you can iterate over the list nd check if the fruit exist in your dictionary

```
for fruit in myFruits:
    # Print the fruit if it has a value of 1
    if fruit in FruitValues and FruitValues[fruit] == 1:
        print(f"{fruit} has a value of {FruitValues[fruit]}")
```

Comment: Ill try to make this work.  My only concern is that the numbers are variable from other process.  They are not hard coded.  Will circle back.

Comment: Your dictionary doesn't have to be hardcoded. That's just an example, but you can get the values from variables, from reading a file... This answer just aims to guide you in the datastructure to use.

Comment: I edited my code above to incorporate the dictionary method.  However when I run it it will just print out all of the fruits (as expected).  Do you know how to tell it to just print out fruit names with an attached value of 1?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: your dictionary has names as keys and values. to print only the ones with value 1 use a conditional. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah not sure if its an issue but it has to be this way for the other parts of my code to work if possible (the key and value having the same name)

Comment: I posted an idea above but doesnt work.

Comment: Just tried your code.  Works perfectly.  Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it at the end.

```
for x, y in FruitValues.items():
    if y == 1:
        print(x)
```